# $A^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges strongly to a projection onto $(\ker{A})^{\perp}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

I want to show the following:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $A\in\mathbb{B}(H)_{+}$ be a positive operator, and let $P$ be a projection onto $(\ker{A})^{\perp}$ (i.e. $(\ker{A})^{\perp}=\{x\in H\mid Px=x\}$). Then, $\{A^{\frac{1}{n}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges strongly to $P$.

First, I tried to the proof for $x\in (\ker{A})^{\perp}$. In other words, I want to show
$$ \|A^{\frac{1}{n}}x-Px\|=\|A^{\frac{1}{n}}x-x\|=\|(A^{\frac{1}{n}}-I)x\|\to0\quad(x\in (\ker{A})^{\perp}).$$
It's embarrassing, but I can't prove $\|(A^{\frac{1}{n}}-I)x\|\to0$. Also, I don't know how to prove for $x\notin(\ker{A})^{\perp}$.

Please teach me that proof, thank you.

Comment: Please clarify the question. For instance $N^{\perp}(A)=\Re( A^{T})$ and it has nothing to do with a projection matrix.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos ? i'm not given any more information on that

Comment: OK! A straightforward proof in the case of matrices with positive or zero elements is that for each element $a_{ij}$ we have $\sqrt[n]{a_{ij}}\to1$ and the result in this case is immediate!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos The $n$th root of a matrix needs not have entries given by the $n$th root of the original matrix.

Comment: @TwelveSakuya Is there any assumption on the dimension of $H$? In particular, is it supposed to be finite?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i think $H$ isn't always finite dim.

Comment: @TwelveSakuya How do you define $A^{\frac{1}{n}}$ when the dimension of $H$ is infinite?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\forall A\in\mathbb{B}(H)_{+}, \exists ! B\in\mathbb{B}(H)_{+}$ s.t. $A=B^n$. I define $A^{\frac{1}{n}}=B$.

Comment: Do you know [Spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Spectral_subspaces_and_projection-valued_measures)?

Comment: @Feng yes ($\sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))$ for poly­nomial $f$, right?)

Comment: More than that. Indeed, I want to use $A=\int_\mathbb R\lambda dE_A(\lambda)$ and something related to functional calculus. I don't know if you are OK with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A=0$ the conclusion is obvious. For $A\neq 0$ we may restrict to  $\|A\|=1$ (as $\|A\|^{1/n}\to 1$ ). Then $\|A^{1/n}\|=\|A\|^{1/n}=1.$ Therefore $0\le A^{1/n}\le I.$ The  sequence $A^{1/n}$ is increasing and bounded above by $I.$
Hence it is strongly convergent to a positive operator $B$ such that $0\le A\le B.$ We have $$A^{1/n}=A^{1/(2n)}A^{1/(2n)}\longrightarrow B^2 \quad {\rm strongly}$$ hence  $B^2=B,$ i.e. $B$ is an orthogonal projection. If $Bx=0$ then $Ax=0. $ Conversely if $Ax=0,$ then $A^{1/n}x=0,$ hence  $Bx=0.$ Therefore $\ker A=\ker B,$ which implies $B=P.$

Comment: Is your first hence easy to see?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven There is a general theorem about increasing and bounded above sequences of positive operators. See Theorem 13.15  in https://tqft.net/web/teaching/2016/Analysis3/LectureNotes/13.Spectral.theory-r.pdf

Comment: wow thank you!!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc wait, why can we restrict to $||A||=1$?

Comment: For  $A\neq 0$ we have $A=tA',$ where $\|A'\|=1$ and $t=\|A\|>0.$ Then $$A^{1/n}=t^{1/n}(A')^{1/n}$$ and $t^{1/n}\to 1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ok ty. also, why $A^{1/n}\le I$?

Comment: Because $\|A^{1/n}\|^n=\|A\|=1.$ For a positive operator the conditions $\|A\|\le 1$ and $A\le I$ are equivalent.